# Openbench Logic Sniffer setup

Tags: logic-analyzer

I finally broke down and bought this board:
http://hackaday.com/2010/02/28/open-source-logic-analyzer-2/

It "seems" like it would be really helpful, the problem I'm having is getting it setup, I am not finding much of a "how to" anywhere. Here are the problems I'm having.

I would like to get it working on both my windows and linux machines, the problem with the windows machine is that using the logic analyzer software I can't see the "capture" button at the bottom of the screen cause of my netbook resolution, and since I can't change my resolution I can't get it working there.

My Ubuntu machine I couldn't find a download for the S/W except in a .exe format, so I had to download and install wine on my machine, but when I plug in my board I'm not sure if it's detected. There appears to be a rxtx module I need to setup and install. But I'm not sure what version I should use. I found links to some of this from the comments (where I in fact commented) here: [Dangerous Prototypes](http://dangerousprototypes.com/2010/02/25/prototype-open-logic-sniffer-logic-analyzer-2/)

does anyone have any good suggestions on what to do at this point?

Also anyone have/know of a clear step by step guide (with possibly copy paste commands for the command line portion? as the wget calls can get hard to read and I'm not sure what the link is most times)

Comment: Try using altdrag to move the window upwards to get to a button that is off the screen: http://code.google.com/p/altdrag/

Comment: I'll give it a try, the problem I seemed to have was that whenever I released (even if I grabbed the bottom of the titlebar area) it would snap back down. That's what I'm worried will happen here, but we'll see...thx for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gadgetfactory.net/logicsniffer/index.php?n=LogicSniffer.Windows

Here are some instructions I posted to the forum on building and running SUMP in Linux:

http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/index.php?topic=549.msg4933#msg4933

Comment: I am in the process of reverting my machine to XP, and then hopefully taking advantage of my Windows 7 upgrade I paid for a while back but never used.

Comment: I do have to add that I was more interested in the linux/ubuntu side of the install, as I've seen this screencast, and that's how I got to the point on my netbook where I found my resolution wouldn't work.

Comment: Added some linux info I originally posted to the user forums

Comment: Thank you for the updates, I'll try to give it a whirl at home, this update will deserve an upvote.... :)

Comment: I don't have internet at home atm, so I haven't messed with the linux side since I can't download anything, BUT I did restore my xp image to my old laptop and brought up the windows side I had already downloaded on my netbook and it looks like everything I needed it to is working (from what I can tell) so now to figure out if I can do it in linux is the real test. -- Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @JobyTaffey can you please update the first link it appears to be dead. I found this which appears to be helpful: http://gadgetfactory.net/logicsniffer/index.php?n=LogicSniffer.Windows

Comment: onaclov200: Completely off-topic, but you don't actually have to install XP in order to use the win7 upgrade. You can install from the win7 upgrade DVD and insert the XP CD when prompted by the installer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your hands on a Windows install disc, you might be better served trying a virtual machine install of Windows on your Ubuntu machine. I know Wine has gotten leaps and bounds better but I've found very few situations where VirtualBox has failed me.

Comment: I know it's REALLY way late, but Windows in a VM wasn't an option, I had 512Mb ram, and a 1.6 GHZ processor...LOL

Answer (score 1):

After being fed up with trying to get rxtx to work on Linux, I decided to write my own command line client called [monosump](https://github.com/Earlz/monosump). It's only dependency is mono(or .Net 4.0 on Windows). It's of course, quite basic, but depending on your needs it might work well for you.